set take_profit = 20 pips on metatrader5 in python
I want to set an order by MetaTrader5 in Python
I want to enter the amount of profit equal to 20 pips when setting the order
How can I do this?

finally i found the answer
just i put tp=Entry + 0.002
and thats is
